# How to switch scss/css file at runtime or switch theme in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a multitheme website using reactjs and created .scss file for defferent theme scheme. I've googled for switch theme in react and mostaly suggested styled component but I dont't want to do this approach.

I have created context as well and switch .scss file on context value but doing .scss file import first import file changes applied only.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using React here, so I suggest you using React Context API.

From my understanding of the documentation, the correct way of doing it is to split style-themes by components, using one stylesheet per component, e.g.

```
.your-component {

  &--light {
    background-color: light;
  }

  &--dark {
    background-color: dark;
  }
}
```

You Can then create Provider and Consumer for your Context, like

```
const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();
```

The Provider would look something like this:

```
default class Provider extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return <Provider value={this.props.theme}>{this.props.children}</Provider>;
  }
}
```

The Consumer:

default class Consumer extends Component {

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Consumer>{theme => this.props.children(defaultTo(theme, this.props.defaultTheme))}</Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, each of your components should look something like this:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Consumer } from '../theme-context';

import './myComponent.scss';



default class MyComponent extends PureComponent {

  _renderMyComponentWithTheme = theme => {


    return (
      <div styleName={`class--${theme}`}>
        Hello World
      </table>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <Consumer defaultTheme="light">{this._renderMyComponentWithTheme}</Consumer>;
  }
}
```

This will then allow you to pass a theme at the top level, and all of your components will have the same theme.

```
import { Provider } from '../theme-context';    
<Provider value="dark">
      <App />
    <Provider>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer